# Why does tcpdump see a reply, but not netcat

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, tcpdump, netcat

I'm debugging a OpenVPN site-to-site connection using UDP in netcat.

I can get packets to flow in one direction (host A->host B), but not the reverse one.

```
root@hosta:~# nc 10.0.3.2 1234 -u

root@hostb:~# nc -l 1234 -u
```

The strange thing is that, when running `tcpdump` in host A, I actually see the UDP packet arriving from host B:

```
root@hosta:~# tcpdump port 1234
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:36:04.695423 IP hosta.46603 > 10.0.3.2.1234: UDP, length 4
17:36:06.484233 IP 10.0.3.2.1234 > hosta.46603: UDP, length 4
```

However, netcat doesn't output anything at all. I've tried `strace` on the `nc`, and nothing is even received from the socket.

What else can I do to diagnose this?

Comment: Check your local hosts firewall to see if you are blocking the traffic.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Good point! `iptables -L` shows the tables are completely empty, with default accept

Answer (score 3):

With only the commands given, this would have been easy! Netcat defaults to TCP without `-u` for UDP. While `nc -lp 1234 -u` listens to UDP connections on port 1234, `nc 10.0.3.2 1234` tries to open a TCP connection instead.

I suggest adding `-v -v` to your Netcat on both ends as it will give you sent/rcvd statistics in the end. Please add this information and also correct the commands you were using so that we could know you had your debugging condition right.

Also use `tcpdump port 1234 -XX` to see what's inside these packets in HEX and ASCII.

---

However, based on the output of `tcpdump port 1234` you probably still had the commands right, but let's play with this mistake a little to see how we can know that:

Since you got UDP packets

```
IP hosta.46603 > 10.0.3.2.1234: UDP, length 4
IP 10.0.3.2.1234 > hosta.46603: UDP, length 4
```

instead of TCP packets like

```
IP hosta.46603 > 10.0.3.2.1234: Flags [S], seq 1384271454, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1969077197 ecr 0,nop,wscale 3], length 0
IP 10.0.3.2.1234 > hosta.46603: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1384271455, win 0, length 0
```

lets assume you had it vice versa:

```
root@hosta:~# nc 10.0.3.2 1234 -u
root@hostb:~# nc -lp 1234
```

But in this case you would only have seen the first

```
IP hosta.46603 > 10.0.3.2.1234: UDP, length 4
```

and there would not have been any UDP packets to the other direction!

Then, if you accidentally used same `nc <IP> 1234 -u` on both ends, you would have both lines, but the ports wouldn't have been the same, but something like:

```
IP hosta.46603 > 10.0.3.2.1234: UDP, length 4
IP 10.0.3.2.73644 > hosta.1234: UDP, length 4
```

Comment: Well spotted, I copied a previous version of the command accidentally. I was originally trying with TCP, but the handshake doesn't succeed, so switched to UDP on both sides (edited on the original question). I do have hostb using -l, so I have no idea what's wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

The reply maybe similar to the response of this question:
[Forwarded packets are visible by tcpdump but not received by application](https://serverfault.com/questions/925484/forwarded-packets-are-visible-by-tcpdump-but-not-received-by-application)

Is hostA in a different network than hostB? Does hostB return to hostA (Does it have a route to hostA? If not, is `net.ipv4.conf.*.rp_filter` disabled?

The solution if hostB hasn't route to hostA is to add a route or disabling `rp_filter` (reverse path filter).

Answer (score 0):

Also, in my hardcoded IPv4 header I got the checksum wrong so that on the receiving end netcat ignored the UDP packet even though tpcdump and wireshark reported it. tcpdump flagged the wrong checksum, wireshark ignored it

Comment: But the question isn't about hard coded bad packets, they are generated by the serder's kernel.