# Forwarded packets are visible by tcpdump but not received by application

Tags: ubuntu, routing, udp

I have 3 machines:

- A 10.8.0.8/24
- B 10.8.0.13/24 10.248.0.34/23
- C 10.8.0.40/24 10.248.0.12/23

On A I add a route from A to C using: `ip route add 10.248.0.12 via 10.8.0.13`.

Then I test the configuration. On C I type `nc -ul 2002`. Then on A I use `nc -u 10.248.0.12 2002` to send some packets.

Packets are not received by `nc` on C.

However when I use on C
`tcpdump -n "(src host 10.8.0.8 and dst host 10.248.0.12) or (src host 10.248.0.12 and dst host 10.8.0.8)" -vv -i any`
then it reads
`15:19:46.756649 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 47699, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 29) 10.8.0.8.44254 > 10.248.0.12.2002: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 1`.

What can I do to inspect what happens with the packets, clearly the packets are routed from A to C, but for some reason they are rejected.

On C:

`iptables -t filter -L FORWARD -n`

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
WEAVE-NPC  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* NOTE: this must go before '-j KUBE-FORWARD' */
NFLOG      all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW nflog-group 86
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network fanbr0 */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network fanbr0 */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

`iptables -t mangle -L -n`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CHECKSUM   udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68 /* generated for LXD network fanbr0 */ CHECKSUM fill
```

Comment: supposition (not enough informations available, nor actual goal): C has a direct route to A via 10.8.0.40/24 . Your setup is doing an assymetric routing, and reverse path filtering triggers (drop)

Comment: @A.B The actual goal is that on C I have an lxc container at 10.248.0.22/23. The container does not have an IP at the 10.8.0.0/24 interface so I need to target the 10.248.0.22 IP. I chose to make a simpler case working first. So the goal of this question is to make the ip 10.248.0.12 accessible from A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81344/discussion-between-a-b-and-marcin-krol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @A.B the explanation is reverse path filtering. I made 10.248.0.12 accessible from A by disabling rp filtering on C.

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`
`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter`

Answer (score 0):

I see rule

*DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0*

before rules

*ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0*

So all forwarded packets on C will be dropped.